# Why does enable_shared_from_this crash if inheritance is not public instead of erroring out

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, private-inheritance, enable-shared-from-this

I was using shared_ptr in a project. And at one point I had to store the raw pointers as a void then later convert it back to its shared_ptr form in a callback where the void* was passed. But for some reason the code kept crashing. I didn't understand why since I wasn't getting any compiler errors or warnings. But I noticed that when I was inheriting from `std::enable_shared_from_this` I wasn't assigning it to be a public inheritance. And that's what was causing the crash.

I wrote an example code and I'm just wondering why it happens.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class TestShared : public std::enable_shared_from_this<TestShared>{
private:
    int32_t id;
public:
    TestShared(int32_t id){
        this->id = id;
    }
    std::shared_ptr<TestShared> getshared(){
        return shared_from_this();
    }
    int32_t getid(){
        return id;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::shared_ptr<TestShared> ts(new TestShared(0xFF));
    void* tsp = ts.get();
    std::shared_ptr<TestShared> tsn = ((TestShared*)tsp)->getshared();
    std::cout << std::hex << tsn->getid();
    return 0;
}
```

So that code will execute and run fine and I get the expected result.

But when I remove public from the inheritance:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class TestShared : std::enable_shared_from_this<TestShared>{
private:
    int32_t id;
public:
    TestShared(int32_t id){
        this->id = id;
    }
    std::shared_ptr<TestShared> getshared(){
        return shared_from_this();
    }
    int32_t getid(){
        return id;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::shared_ptr<TestShared> ts(new TestShared(0xFF));
    void* tsp = ts.get();
    std::shared_ptr<TestShared> tsn = ((TestShared*)tsp)->getshared();
    std::cout << std::hex << tsn->getid();
    return 0;
}
```

Then it results in a crash. So why does `public` make a difference here and why doesn't the compiler give a warning/error?

Comment: Unrelated: why do you need to cast the owned pointer to `void*`? It looks very out of place alongside `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Because I was a using a C library which triggered a callback I had implemented. The object passed into the callback had a user contenxt which was a void*. So I casted my objects to void* as a context to be passed in the callback. The void* in this specific example was just to replicate exactly what I was doing in my project.

Comment: that makes total sense; carry on. I was just concerned you might be doing some sort of type punning or polymorphism hack but it seems you know what you're doing :-)

Answer (score 5):

Being `public` is important because the `shared_ptr` system needs to access the `enable_shared_from_this` base class of the given type. And it can't do that if it's not `public`ly accessible from the given type.

There is no warning/error for a non-accessible base class because there is no way for the system to *know* that your code is wrong.

It is conceptually OK to use a `shared_ptr` constructor that can "enable `shared_from_this`" even if `enable_shared_from_this` is private. Why? Consider the following:

```
class B : public enable_shared_from_this<B> {...};

class D : private B {...};
```

Now, `B` expects to be able to do `shared_from_this` gymnastics. But `D` privately inherited from it. So `D`'s relationship to `B` (and thus to `B::shared_from_this`) is private. Maybe `D` is using `B` in such a way that it doesn't trigger any of the `shared_from_this` usage.

So if `D` is not relying on `B::shared_from_this`, if `B` is just an implementation-detail of `D`, why is it an error if someone puts a `D` in a `shared_ptr`?

There is no test you can come up with which will not give rise to false positives like this. Therefore, if the `enable_shared_from_this` base class is not accessible, then `shared_ptr` constructors that could try to use it simply do not attempt to use it.

Comment: Ah okay so it's a matter of inheritance and semantics itself. Not necessarily to do with shared_ptr?

Comment: @Nina yes, that's right. `private` generally has the semantics of "implementation detail; look away and do not touch." So it makes sense that a class cannot be queried for what it privately inherits from.

Comment: I think that, if you `enable_shared_from_this`, it's because you want to get a shared pointer to `this` from a class method.  I don't know that it's common to have a class that can handle being in both shared and non-shared pointers.  I think I would rather have the false positives.

Comment: > `shared_ptr` system needs to access the `enable_shared_from_this` base class of the given type. 
How is this implemented?

Comment: @B_Dex_Float: The obvious way: `shared_ptr` is a friend of `enable_shared_from_this`, so it can access its internals and play around as needed. This is why your type needs to make `enable_shared_from_this` a `public` base class: so that it can convert a pointer to your type into a pointer to the `enable_shared_from_this` base class.

Comment: Ahh so private inheritance it's not possible for "outsiders" to convert derived* to base*, got it. Thanks for your time!
[Link for reference](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/private-inheritance#priv-inherit-like-compos)

Answer (score 3):

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this

> A common implementation for `enable_shared_from_this` is to hold a weak reference (such as `std::weak_ptr`) to `this`. The constructors of `std::shared_ptr` detect the presence of an unambiguous and accessible (since C++17) `enable_shared_from_this` base and assign the newly created `std::shared_ptr` to the internally stored weak reference if not already owned by a live `std::shared_ptr` (since C++17).

If the inheritance is public, then when `ts` is initialized, it "records" in the `enable_shared_from_this` base subobject that it is the owner of the `TestShared` object. When `getshared` is later called, the base subobject is consulted, and a new `shared_ptr` object is created that shares ownership with `ts`.

If the inheritance is not public, then when `ts` is initialized, it doesn't "know" that there is an `enable_shared_from_this` subobject that it needs to write to. Thus, when `getshared` is called, the `enable_shared_from_this` subobject doesn't contain any information about who currently owns the object. In C++17, this results in an exception; before C++17, the result is undefined.

Comment: So if I had a class that allowed inheritance from it, how would my class know if the child class is doing a public inheritance or a private inheritance? I'm guessing that enable_shared_from_this only allows shared_from_this() to be called under public, but not private?

Comment: @Nina I'm sorry, I didn't understand this: "How would my class if the child class is doing a public inheritance or a private inheritance"

Comment: sorry, I made a typo in the comment. "How would my class Know".

Comment: @Nina a class has no way of knowing what kind of access a derived class specified when inheriting it, and should not need to know. If someone chooses to use private inheritance, they are the ones responsible for not using `enable_shared_from_this`.